# SQL Server CTE to recursively fetch all the linked rows for the given row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following details:

```
-- SQL
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LedgerTbl](
    [LedgerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [Cr Amt] [decimal](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Dr Amt] [decimal](8, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LedgerTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LedgerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
-- Data
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (17, N'L1 Ledger', 20, CAST(25252.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (18, N'L2 Ledger', 20, CAST(9000.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (20, N'Master Ledger', NULL, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(6900.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (45, N'L1.1 Ledger', 17, CAST(361.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (46, N'L1.1.1 Ledger', 45, CAST(6541.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID], [Name], [ParentID], [Cr Amt], [Dr Amt]) VALUES (47, N'L1.1.2 Ledger', 45, CAST(321.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(8, 2)))

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LedgerTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LedgerTbl_LedgerTbl] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LedgerTbl] ([LedgerID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LedgerTbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LedgerTbl_LedgerTbl]
GO
```

The sample data is like this:

```
LedgerID    Name            ParentID     Cr Amt     Dr Amt
20          Master Ledger   NULL           0.00    6900.00
17          L1 Ledger       20         25252.00       0.00
18          L2 Ledger       20          9000.00       0.00
45          L1.1 Ledger     17           361.00       0.00
46          L1.1.1 Ledger   45          6541.00       0.00
47          L1.1.2 Ledger   45           321.00       0.00
```

In the above table for the LedgerID 20, I need all the linked ledgers (in all levels), which are directly or indirectly linked for this ledger. In the above table all ledgers are directly linked to 20.
If I query for balances of ledger 20 it should show like this (adding all the Cr Amt and Dr Amount of all linked ledgers from all levels):

```
Cr Bal        Dr Bal
41475.00    6900.00
```

Since all the ledgers are directly or indirectly linked to 20, all the Cr Amt and Dr Amt are being summed up.
The results should be like this after adding sum of Cr Amt and Dr Amt of all linked/not linked LedgerID's:

```
LedgerID   Tot. Cr Amt  Tot Dr Amt
20         41475.00    6900.00
18          9000.00       0.00
17         32475.00       0.00
45          7223.00       0.00
46          6541.00       0.00
47           321.00       0.00
```

Please notice that ledger 18 does not have any child ledgers and hence no need to add any balances.

Please help to achieve this using CTE or any other method.  Thanks in advance.

This is what I've tried:

```
;WITH RecursiveLedger(LedgerID, [Name],[Cr Amt], [Dr Amt], LevelNum, LevelIndex, ParentID)
AS (
       SELECT lg.LedgerID,
              lg.[Name],
              lg.[Cr Amt],
              lg.[Dr Amt],
              1 AS LevelNum,
              CAST(lg.LedgerID AS VARCHAR) AS LevelIndex,
              lg.ParentID 
       FROM   [LedgerTbl] lg
       WHERE  lg.ParentID IS NULL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT l.LedgerID,
              l.[Name],
              l.[Cr Amt],
              l.[Dr Amt],
              r.LevelNum + 1 AS LevelNum,
              CAST(r.LevelIndex + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.ParentID) AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR) AS LevelIndex,
              l.ParentID 
       FROM   [LedgerTbl] l,
              RecursiveLedger r
       WHERE  r.LedgerID = l.ParentID
   ) SELECT * FROM   RecursiveLedger
```

Comment: For one level I'm getting the result, but for multiple levels I fail to do this using CTE.

Comment: @Nagesh Could you please post your attempt at the CTE?

Comment: @Bridge I have edited and added what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with anc as 
(
    select ledgerid, parentid
    from [LedgerTbl] where parentid is not null
    union all
    select c.ledgerid, isnull(anc.parentid, anc.parentid)
    from anc 
        inner join [LedgerTbl] c on anc.ledgerid = c.parentid
), anc2 as
(
    select * from anc
    union all
    select ledgerid, ledgerid
    from ledgertbl 
)
select  a.parentid,
        sum(l.[Cr Amt]), 
        sum(l.[dr Amt]) 
from anc2 a
    inner join ledgertbl l on a.ledgerid = l.ledgerid
group by a.parentid
order by a.parentid;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I wanted the sum of Cr Amt and Dr Amt. Can you please help me (with sql) to find out all depending ledgers for a given ledger?

Comment: thanks, Kindly help me to get all dependent ledgers for ledger 20 and their dependent ledgers and so on.

Comment: @Nagesh. I've expanded to include sums for all hierarchies. Is this the solution you're after?